# Unhide a hidden Gerrit project

Tags: gerrit

We have a project in Gerrit that is hidden. I have two questions about this 'feature':

1. Where can I find this setting on disk or database so I can verify the state of a project?
2. How can I make a hidden project active again?

I'm admin in Gerrit and have CLI access to the server, so I can access files on the server if that is necessary.

Regards,

Johan-Kees

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The probably easiest way is using the web UI. Access the project settings and change the *State* from *Hidden* to *Active* (you can access this page via https://review.example.com/#/admin/projects/example for project *example*):

[image]

You can also use the `gerrit set-project` SSH command to change a projects visibility (see [docs](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-set-project.html)):

```
$ ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit set-project example --project-state ACTIVE
```

I guess this is saved in the `project.config` in the [refs/meta/config](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-project-config.html), which would be another way.